# Is `Console.In` an instance of `StreamReader`?

Tags: c#, standard-library

In .NET Framework Class Library, a book says that

> `Console.In` is an instance of `TextReader`.

`TextReader` is an abstract class, so how can it have an instance `Console.In`?

`StreamReader` is a derived class of `TextReader`, and is a non-abstract class.
Is `Console.In` an instance of `StreamReader`?

Answer (score 2):

> TextReader is an abstract class, so how can it have an instance Console.In?

You're logically correct, but its (I would say) generally understood that when you say "I have an instance of [an abstract class]" what you really mean is "I have an instance of a concrete class which inherits an abstract class". It's the same with interfaces, you might say "I have an instance of IFoo" where you actually mean "I have an instance of a class which conforms to the contract set out by IFoo".

For your specific question, the [disassembly is available](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Console@cs/1305376/Console@cs) And you can see that you're basically right. The *actual* type is of course a concrete class which inherits `TextReader`. It uses `TextReader.Synchronized` around a `StreamReader` instance.

```
....

tr = TextReader.Synchronized(new StreamReader(s, enc, false, 
                                              _DefaultConsoleBufferSize, false));
....
```

Comment: Upvote for the clearer explanation of the wording. (and just to be complete: under that `StreamReader` there is yet another `__ConsoleStream`, the `s` in the constructor call you show).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Console.WriteLine(Console.In.GetType());
```

The result is

```
System.IO.TextReader+SyncTextReader
```

So `Console.In` is of type `System.IO.TextReader.SyncTextReader` which is a class nested in `TextReader`.

Only the *property* `Console.In` is declared as `TextReader` which `SyncTextReader` obviously derives from.

So in terms of inheritance, the sentence "`Console.In` *is* an instance of `TextReader`" is correct.

---

Update: Indeed (as Jamiec commented) this `SyncTextReader` has an underlying instance of `StreamReader`. This in turn is created with an underlying instance of type `__ConsoleStream`.

Comment: You sure its not just the call to `TextReader.Synchronized` which returns that type. Underneath it does indeed look like a `StreamReader` from the [disassembly](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Console@cs/1305376/Console@cs)

Comment: @Jamiec update my answer with the decoration chain as I could track it down

Answer (score 0):

The base class of *Console.In* is **SynctextReader** which derives from TextReader.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(Console.In.GetType().FullName);
```

gives us

```
System.IO.TextReader+SyncTextReader
```

`SyncTextReader` is nested class inside `TextReader`. It is non abstract, but internal 
See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textreader.cs,311